# Getting more amount of WordPress posts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, api, http

I am trying to get more than the default amount of posts from a WP account, the default is 10, I need at least 20, this is the way I am doing it

```
getBlogs: function($scope) {
  $scope.postsURL = 'http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=20&filter[order]=ASC_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';
  $http.jsonp($scope.postsURL).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.posts = data;
  })
}
```

this is the plug in I am using http://wp-api.org/

[here is a Plnuker just in case](http://plnkr.co/edit/KlfmqW2eLDdEhf90Dsuy?p=preview)

if you put that link for example in POSTMAN, you get an `STATUS 200 OK` but in my app, is giving me an error.

What do you think is happening ?

Comment: Is it possible that your query string is ill-formed, i.e. it should be `http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=20&filter[order]=ASC&jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK` i.e. you have an underscore `_` instead of the ampersand sign `&` before the `json` parameter

Comment: @Val here is a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KlfmqW2eLDdEhf90Dsuy?p=preview let's see what is going on.

Comment: @Val that's the way I need to handle that ```json``` callback here, if I remove that ```_``` then I can not get any of the posts.

Comment: Yes, but you also need to properly separate the `filter[order]=ASC` parameter, too, and that's done with an `&`. You can leave the underscore.

Comment: @Val, yes, it is working now, post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query string is simply ill-formed, i.e. it should read

```
http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=20&filter[order]=A‌​SC&jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK
```

i.e. you need to separate the `_json=...` parameter with an ampersand sign `&`